# AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am adding the following div multiple times on a page.

```
<div class="box span6">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h2 class="custom"><i class="fa-icon-group" style="opacity:.7"></i><span class="break"></span>[TEXT]</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <p><strong>[TEXT 2]</strong></p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat = "course in courses">{{course}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to write a directive but I don't know how to pass values to the directive.

Eg. I want to pass "name" for TEXT and "email address" for "Text 2" and list of books for "courses".

Is there any way to pass values to directive like passing values to a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments to a function are like HTML attributes to a directive. In your link and compile functions, you get an attributes object, which contains the normalised names and values of all the attributes on the element.

For example, you could have `<div data-awesome-directive data-color="red" data-size="16"></div>`. The directive's link function could look like `link: function (scope, element, attributes) { ... }`. In there, you can access the values of the attributes as properties of the object: `attributes.awesomeDirective`, `attributes.color`, and `attributes.size`. Notice how the names are normalised (`awesome-directive` becomes `awesomeDirective`).

For more advanced things, such as function calls or expressions, look into `$parse`. It can parse an expression such as `foo.bar()` and call it on a scope.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

To add on to stevuu's response, if you wanted to pass values to the directive that are variables in the scope you can do so as follows:

```
<div data-awesome-directive data-color="selected_color" ... ></div>
```

where `selected_color` is set in the containing scope. In the link function, the color can be obtained and set in the directive's scope via:

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
  scope.color = scope.$eval(attributes.color);
}
```